# Text Gets Covered When Using Fixed Position in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, fixed

I recently created a webpage for a company at http://www.parkprivatewealth.com/park and everything looked fine on Chrome. However, when using Safari to view the page, the homepage heading gets cut off when using fixed position. The text is there when I try to scroll up more and seems like something is blocking the text.

When I take off the "position: fixed" tag in the CSS the words appear again, would anyone possibly know how to solve the problem?

Comment: We probably need some small example code to help you out here.

Comment: Thanks for responding @Bdawg,
The CSS for the text is this:

.section-banner h1 {
 position: fixed;
 font-family:'Lustria',serif;
 color:#FFF;
 font-weight:4300;
 font-size:80px;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 text-align:center;
 width: 100%;
     height:100%;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 border-top:1.5px solid #fff;
 border-bottom:1.5px solid #fff;
}


I played with it a bunch but it seems like its not the issue except when I make the position fixed, then the text gets covered

Comment: The HTML is just this 

<div class="banner-box">
<h1>Growing With You</h1>
</div>

Comment: Unfortunately, your CSS and HTML didn't work very well as an example, so I updated the link instead.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by updating the link?

Comment: Edits on this site need to be approved, so it probably isn't showing up yet. I changed your url text into an actual hyperlink.

Comment: Ah, Thanks! Sorry, I'm new to the website and this is one of the first websites I've made.

Comment: It's okay, you'll get used to the site soon enough. Welcome to Stack Overflow, by the way.

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem? If so, please accept it. If not, let us know how we can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem:** When the header changes to a `fixed` position, it gets pulled out of the document flow and the .container element pushes upward. Since you didn't use `top`, `left`, etc., the `h1` element moves upward with .container

**The solution:** Add `padding-top` to the .container element. It should be the same as the header height.

Comment: The container was definitely the problem, unfortunately I can't seem to to fit the entirety of the header. I moved the container down (added the 'padding-top' element) but the container doesn't move with the header when the header scrolls. Is there a way to change the height and width of the container?

I tried adding a 'height' and 'width' element but it seemed shift the background picture as well.

Thanks for all the help @bdawg!

Comment: You're very welcome, but sorry, I'm not sure what you are asking in your comment: 

What do you mean you can't "fit the entirety of the header"? 

I didn't mean for you to add any new element, just add the `padding-top` property to the `.container` rule. That should do the trick. 

Why do you want the `.container` element to move with the header? 

Why do you need to change the height and width of the `.container ` element?

Comment: @Edward213 Sorry for all the questions. Just trying to clear up everything I didn't understand to help you out.

Comment: Oh I apologize I complete Understand what you mean now, thank you so much. Unfortunately, it seems like the container I build was for many of the other sections as well, is there a way to just change one container?

Comment: @Edward You can add an id to the one element you need to change, then add a CSS rule. For example, **HTML:**  `<div class="container" id="someId">` **CSS:** `#someId { /* your properties here */ }`